# Attach ggplot image to tweet through Twitter share widget in Shiny app

Tags: html, r, twitter, shiny

I have a Shiny app that includes a widget to share a tweet with some pre-loaded text. It appears on the app as a button that says "Tweet" that sends the text located in the data-text line of the tags$div section of the code. I'd like to be able to also include an image of the ggplot chart in the tweet that's created when people use the Shiny app online.

Is this even possible? I've seen suggestions that Twitter cards may be an option, but I'm not familiar with those or how I would get one to work in this tool.

Below is my minimal reprex. The app is hosted on ffevaluator.com/tools/draftevaluator if you want to see the app in its full form.

ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("draftPlot"),
      tags$div(
        HTML("<div style='float:right'>
             <a href='https://twitter.com/share' 
             class='twitter-share-button' 
             align='middle' 
             data-url='www.mywebsite.com' 
             data-text='Insert text here!' 
             data-size='large'>Tweet
             </a>
             <script>!function(d,s,id){
             var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
             if(!d.getElementById(id)){
             js=d.createElement(s);
             js.id=id;
             js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
             }
             }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
             </script>
             </div>")
        )) )
```

server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$draftPlot <- renderPlot({    
    ggplot() +
      geom_smooth() +
      geom_point() 
  })


}
```

I also posted this on the RStudio Community website (post here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/attach-ggplot-image-to-tweet-through-twitter-share-widget-in-shiny-app/67867) but haven't gotten any responses yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the Twitter web sharing popup (`twitter.com/share`) to include an image, unfortunately. The way a Twitter Card *could* work would be if you were sharing a link to a static web page in the Tweet text, and if that page had some markup which included the image, so that the image would be shown as a preview for the link. I'm not familiar with Shiny as to whether that is something that could work here.